# How to make Japanese characters appear properly?

Tags: javascript, html, safari

To localise the strings on my webpage, my javascript contains string arrays containing the localisable text in different languages.

Everything looks ok in my text editor - the text renders properly. My file encoding is Unicode/UTF8, which is the system default. But when I open the webpage, node of the characters render properly!

Even when I change my system language to japanese (so all regular menus etc are in japanese,the text on my webpage looks messed up.

Expected text:

```
ファイル名として保存する
```

Actual text:

```
ãƒ•ã‚¡ã‚¤ãƒ«åã¨ã—ã¦ä¿å­˜ã™ã‚‹
```

How do I get the text to render properly?

Comment: What's the encoding of the page you're displaying them in? Where's the code that displays them? Is this only happening in Safari? (If not, don't use the tag).

Comment: I'm coding only for safari (this page will be visited only by safari users). The encoding is not specified - it just says <DOCTYPE! HTML>

Comment: Specify it. That's the exact output you'll get if you send UTF-8 and the browser thinks you've sent Latin-1.

Comment: That fixed it. Thanks! If you like you can put that as an answer and I will make it correct! XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your browser is interpreting the UTF-8 bytes you're sending as some ISO-8859 encoding.

Make sure you specify the correct encoding for the page with a Content-type header (preferably) or:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: In fact the most proper way to specify the encoding is in the HTTP header.

Comment: @ArlaudPierre: added parenthetical in edit to specify that (I'd merely implied it by mentioning it first...)

Comment: I know, I know, just trying to be precise.

Comment: What do you mean by content-type header ?What if there is no server accessing the pages I am using?

Comment: If you're not serving the pages over HTTP, use the meta tag for sure, and you're also... doing something rather weird. :)

Comment: John: You did talk about a webpage. Is your webpage not accessible by http?